# How to plot corr.test output?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, correlation

I have two data frames with the same number of rows and a different numbers of columns. I performed `corr.test` from `psych` package using:

```
Correlations <- corr.test(final_x, final_y, use = "pairwise", alpha=0.05, method = "spearman")
```

Now I do have the output (e.g Correlations) after running the `corr.test`. I am able to separately save `Correlation$p` or `Correlation$r` and make a heatmap.

But my question is I want to have a diagonal plot of the `Correlation` itself with `Correlation$p` on the top right of the plot and `Correlations$r` on the bottom left of the plot.

I tried this but was not helpful:

```
corPlot(Correlations,numbers=TRUE,colors=TRUE,n=51,main=NULL,zlim=c(-1,1),
        show.legend=TRUE, labels=NULL,n.legend=10,keep.par=TRUE,select=NULL, pval=NULL,  
        cuts=c(.001,.01),scale=TRUE,cex,MAR,upper=TRUE,diag=TRUE, symmetric=TRUE,stars=FALSE,
        adjust="holm",xaxis=1, xlas=0,ylas=2,gr=NULL,alpha=.75,min.length=NULL)
```

It would be great you give me some help.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This example may help :

```
mcor <- cor(mtcars) # correlation matrix
mcor
mydata=mtcars
library(corrplot)
corrplot(mcor, type="upper", order="hclust", tl.col="black", tl.srt=45) # print correlation
```

To print scatter plot :

```
library("ggpubr")
data=iris
str(data)
ggscatter(data, x = "Sepal.Length", y = "Petal.Length", 
          add = "reg.line", conf.int = TRUE, 
          cor.coef = TRUE, cor.method = "pearson",
          xlab = "xlab", ylab = "ylab")
```

For plotting;

```
library("ggpubr")
library("Hmisc")
mydata=mtcars
mydata.rcorr = rcorr(as.matrix(mydata))
mydata.coeff = mydata.rcorr$r
mydata.p = mydata.rcorr$P
plot(mydata.coeff,mydata.p)
```